# Will photons be recharged in energy if stimulated by an electromagnetic wave?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, photons

Will placing an active electromagnetic coil around a fibre optic cable recharge photons being emitted by it, therefore increasing their distance and energy as they pass through it's field, or is there an alternate method to recharging photons?

Comment: Wrap the fiber optic cable in cladding which reduces the loss of light and/or lower the refractive index of the core.

Comment: Although, by all methods, is it possible to recharge the photons instead of just extending their distance?

Comment: What do you mean by "recharging photons"?  Photons are the quantum of the electromagnetic field - they are what you get when you treat electromagnetic waves quantum mechanically, so EM waves and photons are not two distinct entities in the way you're describing.

Comment: There is a fibre that amplifies laser light, google erbium doped finer, but the fiber is acting like a laser.

Answer (score 1):

> Will placing an active electromagnetic coil around a fibre optic cable recharge photons being emitted by it,

The optical fiber transmits light, which has to be generated by some source.

Light  is a superposition of the quantum mechanical entities called "photons" , the quantum mechanical wave functions of photons add up to the classical electromagnetic wave.

Photons have a fixed energy connected with the frequency of the light they build up, $E=hν$

> therefore increasing their distance and energy as they pass through it's field, or is there an alternate method to recharging photons?

There is no way to "recharge" photons if by this you mean changing their frequency because of the coil  which will be generating photons of different frequency (you call it electromagnetic).

In nature photons can display a different frequency due to the [doppler effect](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/reldop2.html) for light, if the source or the detector is moving, the energy supplied or subtracted by the motion. Higher frequency can  mean "recharging" (source moving towards observer) , but not in the sense you are using it in the question.